# Linux Script does not work properly when execute from Java

Tags: java, linux, process

I have this Script that simply mount the attached External drive and write their mounted path in a text file. Though when I run this script from terminal in tinyCOre it works fine. 
Following is the Code I am using to execute the script, I am using this code throughout my application for mounting and other purposes but non of them have writing to do.

**Code:**

```
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" sh /home/abc/mnt-ddc.sh");
   p.waitFor();
```

I even tried taking the script as array but no help. Quick help will be appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE**
WHen the script is executed from java, nothing happens, no exception thrown, no nothing. I tried all the ways answered below none working.

**mnt-ddc.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
blkid -s LABEL | grep ddc- > ddc.txt        # Get DDC device name and label and write to ddc.txt

perl -pi -e 's/ LABEL="//g' ddc.txt     # Remove text "ddc- from ddc.txt

#perl -pi -e 's/ LABEL="ddc-//g' ddc.txt        # Remove text "ddc- from ddc.txt
perl -pi -e 's/" //g' ddc.txt           # Remove left over text " from ddc.txt

while IFS=: read dev label          # start loop and read device name to $dev and LABEL to $label
do

if mount | grep $dev; then
   echo -e "Already mounted"
else
    if [ ! -d /mnt/$label ]; then
       echo -n "Creating mount point..."
       sudo mkdir /mnt/$label
    fi
        echo -n "Mounting......"$label
    sudo mount $dev /mnt/$label
        echo
    if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
        echo "Mount failed.  Exiting."
        echo "" > ddc.txt
        exit
    fi
fi

done < ddc.txt
```

Comment: You haven't said what actually happens when you run the script from Java, and what the script contains.

Comment: How about using /bin/sh instead of just sh?

Comment: @JimGarrison Please see the Script Code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you notice the space in front of "sh"? Why spawn a new shell? I would make the script directly executable (e.g. `chmod +x /home/paftdl/NavData/mnt-ddc.sh`) and then just call it -

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/paftdl/NavData/mnt-ddc.sh");
InputStream is = p.getInputStream(); // Let's print what we get.
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: this really helped! However, it is not writing to file.

Comment: You need to set your working dir (or update your script to be explicit about the output file path); that is `    File workingDir = new File("/home/paftdl/NavData/");` and then `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/paftdl/NavData/mnt-ddc.sh", null, workingDir);`

Answer (score 0):

Although it is better to use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

The problem you are having is that you have a space in front of `sh`

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh /home/paftdl/NavData/mnt-ddc.sh");
p.waitFor();
```